# Предлагается к продаже или к покупке, если предложение адресовано покупателю?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Терзает сомнение: не могу поверить, что в распространенной среди продавцов недвижимости формулировке "предлагается к продаже" нет логической ошибки. Если предложение поступает покупателю, не должен ли продавец предлагать что-то "к покупке"?

Answer (score 2):

В нацкорпусе всего три предложения с выражением "предлагается к продаже", вот два из них:

"...синдикатом выпущенного займа, с целью подбирать то, что *предлагается к продаже* слабыми **держателями**, нередко готовыми продавать облигации по какой угодно цене, лишь бы только сбыть их с рук. [В. Н. Коковцов. Из моего прошлого]"

"А вот когда невинность сама *предлагается к продаже* за маленький золотой, как я в России видела, или за гинею, как вы можете в Уайтчапеле в любое время получить, ― это чудовищный показатель, от которого не отделаешься рассуждениями ни о психопатии тех, кто покупает, ни о корыстности и порочности тех, кто продается и продает. [А. В. Амфитеатров. Марья Лусьева за границей (1911)]"

Это непопулярное выражение надо понимать так: **КЕМ-ТО предлагается к продаже ЧТО-ТО** (первый пример), или ЧТО-ТО предлагает к продаже СЕБЯ (второй пример).

Выражение "предлагается к покупке" в нацкорпусе отсутствует, принять его как норму ещё сложнее, чем "предлагается к продаже".

Answer (score 0):

Предлагается к продаже. Продавец продает товар, поэтому может предложить его к продаже.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, "товар предлагается к продаже" имеет смысл "кому-то предлагается заняться продажей этого товара", но на практике в это выражение вкладывают другой смысл (увы). С этой точки зрения "предлагается к покупке" логичнее, но почему-то не вошло в употребление. Здесь, возможно, оказало влияние выражение "выставить на продажу", но "выставить на продажу" - вполне корректно (выставить, чтобы продать).